# using strtok() in c with combined word

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'd like to know how to use `strtok` to find values, so is this possible to use `strtok(mystring, "")` or no?

I want split this : `mystring` --> `%3456` I want split into 2 parts : `"%"` and `"3456"`. Is this possible? how can I do that?

Comment: Are you serious? How would `strtok()` know that it should not split at the `"4"` instead of the `"%"`, if you are able to answer that I will never write code again.

Comment: Is it always like that? where does `"%3456"` come from? You see, as it is you can just use `mystring[0]` for the `"%"` and `&mystring[1]` for the rest. But it depends on the context, and whether or not white spaces can be present and ignored in the source string.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `strtok` for this purpose: `strtok` will modify its first argument, overwriting the first *separator* with a `'\0'`.

Use `strspn` or `strcscn()` to scan for sequences of known characters, and copy the sequences into a separate buffer with `memcpy`.